# Replace Array Value with Array Value

Tags: powershell

I want to replace a template of data `$Arraytest` with actual data from an XML file `Arraytest2`.

So I to replace the `$Arraytest.Values` with those from `$Arraytest2.Values` and save them for further process.

```
$Arraytest = @{
    TLC     = 'TLC'
    Crew3LC = 'Crew3LC'
    MyText  = 'MyText'
}

$Arraytest2 = @{
    TLC     = 'FWE'
    Crew3LC = 'KMU'
    MyText  = 'Hello'
}

foreach ($Value in $Arraytest) {
    $Value.Values
}
```

Comment: @JamesC. This will not create a clone, it sets a reference. Changes made to `$arraytest` will also be present in `$arraytest2`

Comment: Edit fail, I'd deleted `.Clone()` somehow. Added as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects are hashtables, not arrays:

```
$Arraytest | Get-Member

TypeName: System.Collections.Hashtable
```

So you can update using the built in hashtable keys:

```
$Arraytest = @{
    TLC      = 'TLC'
    Crew3LC  = 'Crew3LC'
    MyText   = 'MyText'
}

$Arraytest2 = @{ 
    TLC      = 'FWE'
    Crew3LC  = 'KMU'
    MyText   = 'Hello'
}

foreach($key in $($Arraytest.keys)){
    $ArrayTest[$key] = $ArrayTest2[$key] 
}

$ArrayTest

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                 
Crew3LC                        KMU                                                                                                                                                                                   
TLC                            FWE                                                                                                                                                                                   
MyText                         Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) for a shallow copy:

```
$Arraytest = $Arraytest2.Clone()
```

A shallow copy will be fine for this case, but see [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) for further info on this.